# How to add an additional custom column with select * all in Google Sheet Query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How would you do this query in Google Sheet? I have 24 columns in my data so I would not like to enter all column names into the query.

If this is not possible for QUERY, then what is the alternative?

I want something like this:

```
select *, 'ICS' 
label 'ICS' 'Type'
```

But I get an error doing so:

```
> Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or
> more rows.
```

This is the result I want to display:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igccv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),"select * where Col"& 'Static Data'!$B$19 &" is not null",1) ,{"TYPE";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("ICS;",COUNT(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!B:B"))),";"))}}
```

Comment: Hi I tried using your technique but it still shows an error

`={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),"select * where Col4 is not null",1)
,{"TYPE";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!A2:A")="",,"ICS"))}}`

Rows are in the thousands

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please first link the sheets with something like `IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!A1")`

Comment: Corrected. Please check.

Comment: thank you. this worked in the original worksheet

Comment: Final formula looks like this...

`={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),"select * where Col"& 'Static Data'!$B$19 &" is not null",1) ,{"TYPE";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("ICS;",COUNT(IMPORTRANGE('Static Data'!$B$2,"MASTERFILE!B:B"))),";"))}}`